# Create Chat in WebApplication Java

Tags: java, chat

I have a java web application with servlet and java class in backend, and ajax and jsp in frontend that I deploy on Tomcat6. I would create a chat service for the users of my application. What kind of technology can I use?

I have a jsp footer.jsp that is common to other jsp page, in this jsp I would create a popup like facebook for chat comunication. I have in the hashmap of context application the user logged, I don't know how create a java listner for send and recive message from user logged and other. what kind of technology I must use for create a backend and frontend listner?

Comment: What results did you get using your favorite search engine?

Comment: @FelixKling, this stackoverflow question came up in my favorite search engine. :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you know / want to learn and also what functionallity the application should have... why not just add to your current application ? use JSP for the front end, use AJAX for communication - the servlet for the server .....

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130366/taking-input-variables-from-a-tablehtml-and-supply-the-values-as-a-variable-na

Answer (score 0):

i think you would need some ajax long polling  or Jabber.